# Enthalpy of adsorption and adsorption rate

Tags: enthalpy, free-energy, adsorption

What I want to know is about the adsorption enthalpy change by the change of surface coverage and the adsorption rate. In general situations, adsorption would be exothermic. So in the Gibbs free energy equation ${\displaystyle \Delta G^{\circ }=\Delta H^{\circ }-T\Delta S^{\circ }}$, adsorption usually fixes molecules on the surface of the adsorbent so $\Delta S^{\circ}$ is negative and therefore, the higher absolute value of negative $\Delta H^{\circ }$ would cause the adsorption to be more spontaneous. Can this change of spontaneity affect the rate of adsorption if the pressure and temperature are same? If not, what causes the adsorption rate to decrease when surface coverage increases in the same temperature, pressure and concentration?

Comment: I think you mean $\Delta S^ \circ$ is negative because entropy $S^\circ$ itself is always positive. Are you?

Comment: Yes. I think I made a mistake there